# JAI FileLoad/FileStore Operations vs JAI ImageRead/ImageWrite Operations. Differences?

Tags: java, api, javax.imageio, jai

What are the differences between JAI's FileLoad/FileStore operations and its ImageRead/ImageWrite operations?

Is one set better than the other in any way? Which ones should be used as a default?

Comment: Still no answers, even after a bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileLoad](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html) is the operation used in JAI Image I/O to "load" images, while [ImageRead](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-imageio-1_0-rc-docs/com/sun/media/jai/operator/ImageReadDescriptor.html) is the operation used in JAI to "read" images, using Java Image I/O Framework.

The first one requires JAI plus the Image I/O that provides more codecs, like JPEG 12bit.

The seconds one requires JAI only, as the codecs used are the provided with Java platorm.

For most cases, the second one is simple and supports for many popular formats (JPEG, GIF, PNG...), you can use also in applets with 100% pure Java implementation (software) of take advantage of native acceleration.

There are plenty of options, but I recommend the second one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Didn't think this question would ever be answered.